# What is the difference between auto and auto&?

Tags: c++

Here is my code. According to the print results, there is no difference, then what does the & symbol play here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Print test data\n" << std::endl;
    int a[5] = { 23,443,16,49,66 };

    for (auto &ii : a)
    {
        std::cout << "auto ii: " << ii << std::endl;
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (auto jj : a)
    {
        std::cout << "auto jj: " << jj << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: `&` here denotes reference to that variable

Comment: It's the same as the difference between e.g. `int` and `int&` or `MyClass` and `MyClass&`.

Comment: Why are you using `<stdio.h>` and `printf` in a C++11 program? `std::cout << "\n";` works just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto, `for(auto x : range)`: This usage will create a copy of each element of the range.
Auto &, `for(auto& x : range)`: when you want to modify the elements in range (without proxy class reference processing), use auto&.

`ii` is a reference, so in the loop body, if `ii` is modified, the corresponding element in `a` will also be modified.

`jj` is not a reference. In each loop, it is a copy of the corresponding element. Its modification will not affect the corresponding element in `a`. Since each loop creates a copy, it will bring system overhead.

If you want to ensure that the data in `a` is not modified and you want to improve the efficiency, you can use the form `const auto & ii : a`.